# How to convert Django CMS datetime to Vuejs

Tags: datetime, vue.js, django-templates

I've got a Json with opening hours data from Django CMS, I want to import them to a vuejs app. The main problem is to convert the datetime format to JS date.

I've tried with new Date() but I miss something.

The opening hours Json

```js
var jsonoh = [{
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Monday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}, {
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Tuesday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}, {
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Wednesday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}, {
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Thursday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}, {
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Friday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}, {
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Saturday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}, {
  'pm_start': datetime.time(19, 0),
  'name': 'Sunday',
  'am_start': datetime.time(11, 0),
  'pm_stop': datetime.time(23, 30),
  'am_stop': datetime.time(16, 0)
}]
```

Comment: Can't you better format your date/time to send to the Vue-js? It seems like the data that Vue is having to deal with isn't constructed in an way to parse

Comment: Indeed, for now it's the only way I find to parse it. Thanks for the reply :)